# Entities are unmanaged when using Extended PersistentContext

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence

Environment:

```
  JDK 1.8
  WildFly 10.0.0.Final
```

I have following @Stateful bean

```
@Stateful
@SessionScoped
@Local(CdiStatefulEmployeeService.class)
public class CdiStatefulEmployeeBean implements CdiStatefulEmployeeService {

  @PersistenceContext(name = "employees", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
  EntityManager extendedEm;

  private Employee cached;

  @Override
  public String service() {
    cached = extendedEm.find(Employee.class, 499983);
    return cached.getFirstName();
  }

  @Override
  public String updateEntity() {
    cached.setFirstName("Uri2");
    //extendedEm.flush();   -- Line 1
    return cached.getFirstName();
  }
}
```

and following Servlet client

```
@WebServlet("/atInjectedStatefulEjbClient")
public class AtInjectedStatefulEjbClient extends HttpServlet {

  @Inject
  CdiStatefulEmployeeService statefulBean;

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();

    pw.println(statefulBean.service());
    pw.println();
    pw.println(statefulBean.updateEntity());

    session.invalidate();
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
  }
}
```

Observation: Calling bean.updateEntity() method is not automatically saving the changes i.e. setting first name to "Uri2".

Question : Arent the entities managed across the calls in case of extended persistence context ?

Calling the flush() (i.e. uncommenting Line 1) has no effect either. Basically the entity is not managed in the updateEntity() call. I find this strange. Any thoughts ?

### UPDATE:

Just to rule out the possibility, tried with same code but with following

- No @SessionScoped
- No @Inject (replaced with JDNI lookup inside servlet doGet())
- Added @Remove method in the bean
- Have servlet doGet() invoke @Remove once it is done with calling other 2 methods

Result : Same issue. Entity is not managed after first service call

Rakesh

Comment: I disagree. The updateEntity() method is inside EJB that has default transaction policy. If the emp.setFirstName() is called in servlet class then i agree that its not expected to persist the change. But thats not the case here.

Comment: By default the TransactionAttributeType is REQUIRED so you should have  you're changes saved on database. Aren't you somewhere overriding this behavior?

Comment: That was what my expectation too i.e. changes saved to DB automatically. Nope. No transaction attribute changes at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in WildFly. All the documentation (Spec, books etc..) point out that Extended context meant to prevent entities from becoming detached when the transaction ends.

Filed Wildfly Issue : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6383

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `service` method is called before `updateEntity` shows described behavior: Transaction attribute of `service` method is default, which means that, as you pointed out in your comment on `updateEntity`, the transaction is committed at end of `service` call. This commit makes the `cached` entity unmanaged. I suggest to annotate `service` method with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` which should keep `cached` entity managed and subsequent call of `updateEntity` finds managed entity.

Usually, with extended persistence contexts the facade EJB classes are annotated with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` and only EJB's methods that should commit get a different transaction attribute (see for example article [Domain-driven design with Java EE 6](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078042/java-app-dev/domain-driven-design-with-java-ee-6.html)).

Comment: Hmm, logically that doesn't sound correct. Reason : the spec clearly says that the extended entity manager spans multiple transactions. Adding to it, the spec also has similar example. That said, it shouldn't matter who and how transactions are demarcated. Nevertheless, gave it a try and the result is same i.e. the entity is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever inject STATEFUL (session dependent) beans into servlets (used by many users = by many sessions). If you use CMT the commit of the transaction will be executed after the call of the @Remove marked method. Where is it? It can be empty but it is critical at stateful beans.

But It would be a viable solution:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{employeeMB.emplyeeName}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{employeeMB.onSubmit}"/>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@Getter
@Setter
public class EmployeeMB
{
  private String employeeName;

  @EJB
  private EmployeeSB employeeSB;

  public void onSubmit()
  {
    employeeSB.persist( employeeName );
    employeeName = "";
  }
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EmployeeSB
{
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public void persist( String employeeName_ )
  {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setName( employeeName_ );
    em.persist( e );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its just test code thats why i did it that way. If you see my next update in OP, i had switched it to JNDI Lookup to rule out the strange behaviour. Coming back to your suggestion, i find it strange that stateful transactions only commit when @Remove is called. Doesn't it mean that the stateful beans doesn't honour the transaction boundaries ?